# Slow upload speed

Tags: networking

my upload speed is much to slow. I have 2 networkcards RTL8111/8168/8411. Download speed is ok but upload speed is much to slow, about 150 mbps. i installed Windows 7 on the system en there was no problem at all! i went back to Ubuntu 15.10 server edition. I set the cards on full duplex 1000mbit, Ipv6 is not running. I have 500/500 fiber glass.
Please help!

---

ethtool:

```
Settings for enp1s0f0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

---

```
$ iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

 iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

```
$ ethtool -i enp1s0f0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version:
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

I have the accurate drivers for the network cards.

Comment: Check Your `MTU` settings in Your adapter, also please provde `output` for these commands: `ethtool eth0`, `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`

Comment: Please check if You have accurate drivers for Your network cards, according to [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94770/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-but-not-windows-using-a-rtl8111?rq=1) there were issues with the speed caused by the drivers.

Comment: Whats Your MTU value? `ip link list`

Comment: ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:ab:80:17:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:ab:80:19:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Answer (score 1):

Install another driver for this Ethernet card. Run

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

and reboot.

Comment: It's not working for me, still poor upload speed

Comment: how do you measure upload speed?

Comment: speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from XS4ALL Internet BV (************)...
Selecting best server based on latency...
Hosted by INTERACTIVE 3D B.V. (Rotterdam) [32.49 km]: 9.211 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 487.32 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 183.36 Mbit/s

Comment: Whit windows installed its up to 580 Mbit/s