# Ethernet is on 100Mb/s instead of 1000Mb/s

Tags: networking, ethernet

I need help to get running my ethernet to 1000Mb/s. My system is Ubuntu 22.04
Here my spec:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
21:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    DeviceName: Broadcom 5762
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7a32]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
```

I don't know how to configure it. Or do I miss any driver?

Edit:

```
❯ ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: on (auto)
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Edit:

```
❯ sudo dmesg | grep eno1
[sudo] Passwort für dejo: 
[    4.229678] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   32.100596] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   32.100680] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: Link Speed was downgraded by SmartSpeed
[   32.100849] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[  511.579395] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[  511.579478] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: Link Speed was downgraded by SmartSpeed
[  624.201707] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[  624.201790] igb 0000:17:00.0 eno1: Link Speed was downgraded by SmartSpeed
```

What is this SmartSpeed?

Comment: Before looking at the computer, have you confirmed that the *cable* can support gigabit? It should be CAT5e, CAT6, CAT7, or CAT8. If it is CAT5 *without* the "e", then you will not get gigabit speeds. Be sure that the entire network stack that the computer is connected to also supports gigabit. If even one wire or network switch maxes out at 100mbit, then the connection may be downgraded.

Comment: My 5e would not give me the gig speeds. It works great once I replaced all cable with 6 and any switches with full gig support.

Comment: Yes, the cable is good. I connected my notebook with the same cable and everything works as expected. The problem is driver/software...

Comment: Get the name of your ethernet adapter using `ip a` (for example, _`enp3s0f1`_), then run (for example) `ethtool` _`enp3s0f1`_, and paste the output into your original question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Did you try to follow the answers at 
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/94770/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-but-not-windows-using-a-rtl8111 ? Did you try to change the speed manually?

Comment: I tried to boot from stick, and the problem persist. Maybe the onboard LAN is defect? And changing the speed manually was not successful. I could not connect. My chipset is not Realtek.

Comment: Hi, I have experimented since then. It seems that the cable or the keystone could be the problem. In the neighboring room is another cable of same type leading to the router. Connecting the system to this cable it works with 1000Mb/s. I mentioned already that our notebooks work on (damaged) cable with 1000Mb/s where I noticed that both have the broadcoms BCM Chipset. I bought two NICs one with BCM Chipset and the other without. Guess what? The NIC with BCM Chipset did it. Now I have 1000 Mb/s. The other NIC is capable to deliver upto 2500Mb/s and it delivered only 100Mb/s. What do you think?